# Exact same Cocoon form on other model sends other paramaters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the cocoon gem for a nested attributes form, in this case `Projectuser` has_many `ContractLinks`. This all works fine, when I add a contract, it sends the form parameters as `contract_links_attributes`:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "projectuser"=>{"project_id"=>"538", "user_id"=>"56", "contract_links_attributes"=>{"description"=>"test", "contract_link"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Now I want also have a `Project` has_many `ContractLinks`, so I changed the relationship to be polymorphic. This still works great for the `Projectuser`, but not for the `Project`. I reused the exact same form partial, but instead of sending the form paramters as `contract_links_attributes`, it sends it as `contract_links`. This results in an unpermitted paramater error of course. So why is the exact same form partial sending different parameter values?

This is the form for both `Project` and `Projectuser`:

```
    = f.fields_for(:contract_links) do |contract_link|
      = render "contract_link_fields", f: contract_link
```

And this is `contract_link_fields`:

```
%tr.contract
  %td= f.date_select :contract_date, include_blank: true, start_year: 10.year.ago.year
  %td= f.text_field :description, class: "input-xlarge"
  %td= f.text_field :contract_link, class: "input-xlarge"
```

Comment: Can you show us the association definition for both models? I am guessing you are missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ion `Project`?

Comment: You are right, completely forgot to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, thanks! If you add this as an answer, I will give you the credits for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you are missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract_links` in `Project`.

The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method adds/defines the `contract_links_attributes` method, and the `fields_for` uses this method/index-key only if it is available.

Also see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html